# Boolean algebra: can it be simplified even further?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Can it be simplified even further?

[image: Can it be simplified even further?]

Comment: For a systematic approach to these simplifications, you should look into [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

Answer (score -1):

$$\overline{b_2} \overline{b_3} + b_0 \overline{b_1} b_2 + \overline{b_0} \overline{b_1} \overline{b_2} $$

Comment: Hmm yeah, but I did not get the process :) What rule did you use? Sorry about that ! :D

Comment: I used Maple's [BooleanSimplify](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Logic/BooleanSimplify) function.